# Cuelinks API integration

Tags: php, json, api

I want to integrate the API to display merchant details of an Affiliate site API. 
Params
Param name  Description
token 
optional
Your Unique API Key (32 Characters) - Required in the Header

Example: curl https://www.cuelinks.com/api/v1/all_merchants.json -H 'Authorization: Token token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"'

Value: Must be String
sort_column 
optional
Column Via which You want to Sort the Data. Expected Values are name and id.

Default: 'name', Sorts by Name.

Value: Must be String
sort_direction 
optional
Sorting Order for Data. Espected Values are 'desc' and 'asc'

Default: 'asc', Sorts in Ascending Order.

Value: Must be String
page 
optional
Useful for pagination results and getting data per page.

Default: 1

Value: Must be Integer
per_page 
optional
Specify how many records to be returned per page. If you want all the merchants, then pass a large value.

Default: 300

Value: Must be Integer
search_term 
optional
A Search term via which you wants to fetch the records. Very useful for finding merchants starting with a particular character

Default: Blank String

Value: Must be String

These above are the codes and parameters with example that I want to integrate .So, please integrate the code so that I can retrieve results of merchant details in php variable.???
Please help, my email is contact@tutorduniya.com

Answer (score 0):

Cuelinks have updated their V2 with better docs and code sample, you can try it.

http://docs.cuelinks.apiary.io/#reference/api-methods/campaigns/get-campaigns?console=1

You might be looking for the below code snippets.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "/v2/campaigns.json?sort_column=id&sort_direction=asc&page=1&per_page=50&search_term=Flipkart&country_id=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Authorization: Token token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
  "Content-Type: application/json"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);